# Exactly the same behavior between Java String.getBytes() and Python string -> bytes?

Tags: java, python, arrays

In my Java code I have the following snippet :

```
String secret = "secret";
byte[] thebytes = secret.getBytes();
```

I would like to have **exactly** the same result in python. How can I do that ?

```
secret = 'secret'
thebytes = ??? ??? ???
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

In addition, it will be interesting to have the solution for Python 2.x and 3.x

Comment: What's the result of `secret.getBytes()`?

Comment: Which version of Python? String handling was dramatically updated in Python 3 to make Unicode sensible.

Comment: Unicode not needed. But I think that it will be interesting if there's a solution :-)

Comment: In Python 2.x, `str` *is* bytes. The `str` type represents bytes. It contains bytes. How would you like to have the bytes, what do you want to do with them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not as simple as it might first seem, because Python has historically conflated byte arrays and strings. The short answer, in Python 3, is

```
secret = "secret"
secret.encode()
```

But you should read up on how Python deals with unicode, strings and bytes.

Comment: `str` in Python 2.x is a string of bytes. If you want their byte value as an integer then `map(ord, secret)`, as @Linus said.

Answer (score 8):

In python-2.7 there's [`bytearray()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bytearray):

```
>>> s = 'secret'
>>> b = bytearray(s)
>>> for i in b:
...    print i
115
101
99
114
101
116
```

If this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about *exactly* the same, since Python doesn't have `byte`, but this might do the trick:

```
bytes = [ord(c) for c in "secret"] # => [115, 101, 99, 114, 101, 116]
```

Or using `map`, as katrielalex suggested, just because it's pretty:

```
bytes = map(ord, "secret") # => [115, 101, 99, 114, 101, 116]
```

Comment: `map(ord, "secret")` not showing as you display in above sample array. It shows as `<map object at 0x0000026298F0F940>`. Please guide me how to get byte array

Comment: SUPER DUPER LATE but here it is...

`list(map(foo, iterable))`